# Please give a hand on how to join the tables

Tags: codeigniter

I use the below query can retrieve the last record of A and C from `table_name`.

```
select * from 
( select *,row_number() over(partition by A order by B desc) rn
    from table_name 
) a where rn=1
```

the `Table_name` contains field A, B (date), C (int) and I have another table `Table_NameB` with field A, C_P, C_N (sample value as per below )

```
A,  C_P,     C_N
1, 1,       10
2, -10,     -20
3, 1,       100
```

I want to join this table and calculate the value on the fly

if `Table_Name` contains

```
A,B, C
1, 2019-01-01,1000
2, 2019-02-02,  -15
3,  2019-02-03, 0
```

Could you help on how to get the below output by joining the `Table_NameB` ?

the result will be

```
A, C, C_P, C_N 
1, 1000, 1, 10, OVER <-- as 1000 > 1 > 10
2, -15, -10, -20, NORMAL <-- as -15 >-10 >-20
3, 0, 1, 100, UNDER <-- as 0 < 1 < 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT tablea.a, tableb.c, tablea.C_P, tablea.C_N, 
   (CASE
        WHEN tableb.c > tablea.C_P AND tableb.c > tablea.C_N THEN "OVER"
        WHEN tablea.C_N > tablea.C_P AND tablea.C_N > tableb.c THEN "NORMAL"
        WHEN tableb.c < tablea.C_P AND tableb.c < tablea.C_N THEN "UNDER"
    END   
   ) as result
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN tableb ON (tablea.a = tableb.a)
```

You may check more detail over [go4smart](http://www.go4smart.com)

Comment: Could you please advise me what went wrong from our query ?!

Comment: select sensor.Alert_Positive , sensor.Alert_Negative, a.reading, 
(case when a.reading > sensor_alert_positive and a.reading > sensor.Alert_Negative then "OVER"
 end) as result 
 from sensor 
 inner join 
 (select * from ( select *, row_number() over (partition by sensorreading.sensorname order by SensorReading.date_reading desc ) rn from sensorreading )
a where rn=1) on (sensor.SensorName = a.sensorname)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It seems like you are missing "FROM" before table name in inner query. check this out:select sensor.Alert_Positive , sensor.Alert_Negative, a.reading,  (case when a.reading > sensor_alert_positive and a.reading > sensor.Alert_Negative then "OVER" end) as result from sensor inner join (select *  from ( select *, row_number() over (partition by sensorreading.sensorname 
                          order by SensorReading.date_reading desc 
                        ) rn from sensorreading ) a where rn=1
                  ) on (sensor.SensorName = a.sensorname)

Comment: We can optimize this query if you let me know what exactly you want to achieve.